# Load image from internal memory and display it

Tags: javascript, android, image, file, cordova

Hello Im developing an android app, I have few image files saved in the internal memory of the android device. How can I display them on the app.

The images are in the directory `/storage/emulated/0/images_to_display`

I'm using javascript. I want to display these images from that particular folder.

**Also it would be nice if those images displayed in the App are updated (with newer ones) every time I go to that part of the app (images are updated in the device internal memory by another operation, the image file name won't be changed though)**

Any help is appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide any information about what kind of app (Cordova, ReactNative, whatever) you use, it's hard to answer.

For Cordova, maybe you can look at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/

Comment: Im using cordova.

Comment: Yaroslav, can you give me steps on how to do it?
Im using cordova and this is what I wanted. Reading the document made me lil confused. Can  you please  help me a bit

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I remember to use it for file manipulations, but it has been almost a year since I touched Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

```
      first compile   in gradle
  compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
```

then

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                .build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file://" + "/storage/emulated/0/images_to_display");
```

Comment: Im using Javascript . How can I convert it to javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

add plugin : `cordova-plugin-file`

on the device ready call back add :
`window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, fail);`

in the `<body>` add : `<img src="/storage/emulated/0/path-to-file/img.png">`

Comment: Also add permission : 
`<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" /> ` in the `config.xml` file